# I'm getting an error of incorrect usage of flutter_sim_country_code package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run my flutter project or run pub get command I got this error. I studied the code in my flutter project and I didn't use of this plugin however I couldn't found flutter_sim_country_code plugin usage.
The error mention below.

```
The plugin `flutter_sim_country_code` doesn't have a main class defined in E:\flutter_windows_2.0.2-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sim_country_code-0.1.1\android\src\main\java\com\example\flutter_sim_country_code\FlutterSimCountryCodePlugin.java or E:\flutter_windows_2.0.2-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_sim_country_code-0.1.1\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_sim_country_code\FlutterSimCountryCodePlugin.kt. This is likely to due to an incorrect `androidPackage: com.example.flutter_sim_country_code` or `mainClass` entry in the plugin's pubspec.yaml.
    If you are the author of this plugin, fix the `androidPackage` entry or move the main class to any of locations used above. Otherwise, please contact the author of this plugin and consider using a different plugin in the meanwhile.
```

**pubspec.yaml**
version: 1.0.0+1

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  flutter_map: ^0.13.1
  textfield_search: ^0.7.0
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.7.3
  flutter_tags: ^0.4.9+1
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  lottie: ^0.7.0+1
  #qr_code_scanner: ^0.3.1
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+1
  flutter_credit_card: ^0.1.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  toast: ^0.1.5
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  firebase_core: ^1.1.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.4
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.4
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.7
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  readmore: ^1.0.1
  maps_launcher: ^2.0.1
  flutter_html: ^2.0.0
  location: ^4.3.0
  geocoder: ^0.2.1 
  stripe_payment: ^1.0.9
  dio: ^4.0.0
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^3.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  crypto: ^2.1.5
  apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  flutter_native_timezone: ^1.0.4
  #flutter_barcode_scanner: ^0.1.7
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0
  colorful_safe_area: ^0.2.1
  flutter_share: ^2.0.0
  in_app_review: ^2.0.2
  get_version: ^0.2.2
  country_calling_code_picker: ^2.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+4
  facebook_app_events: ^0.13.4
  flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.2
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: I tried to add flutter_sim_country_code on my project, it works without any error and I can get my country code correctly.

Comment: If you don't use that plugin, can you add your pubspec.yaml plugin? May some plugin you used depend on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case i have issue with package name `"androidPackage: com.example.flutter_sim_country_code"` which is not match with my actual package name `"androidPackage: com.myappbuilder.flutter_sim_country_code"`. hence it wasn't work.

If anyone face the same issue then you have to check your package name first in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a plugin problem. Instead, I would recommend you to use alternative plugin.

Use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/carrier_info):

```
String carrierInfo = await CarrierInfo.isoCountryCode;  // The ISO country code for the user’s cellular service provider.
```

Comment: I did not use this flutter_sim_country_ code plugin but still I get error in my code.

Comment: Share your pubspec.yaml code, it is possible that some other plugin is using it.